# Attaching existing order (order.email) to create an account, Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**This is the scenario I would like to accomplish:**

1. User creates an order (enters email into order table).
2. User is sent order confirmation email with link to sign up.
3. If User decides to sign up, it will connect to the account.

What would it take to accomplish this?

I'm a bit mixed up because the `Order` is already created and wouldn't have a `current_user` for the order model to attach to the `User` model.  How would I then have it so the `order.buyer_id` (which is used for the `current_user` of the User who creates the Order) then gets associated with the to-be-signed up User who just created the order.  How could I somehow embed this information in the "sign up" link that gets sent?  To somehow say "if this email signs up and is confirmed, become the buyer_id for said order"?

Also, is this good practice?

**Other option:**

Or should I just have a "email" and "password" field when checking out where the User field get sent ahead of the payment token so the order attaches to the `current_user`?

Does anyone have other ideas or what I should do?

Other than this, the only thing I'm currently doing is a simple "sign up before ordering if you want to save your orders"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is unique for each user so after user signed up and account created you can run a small query where you assign created user to orders. It can be accomplished in the model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :connect_orders

  ...

  def connect_orders
    Order.where(email: self.email).updated_all(buyer_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you that makes some sense.  I play around with that.  I also found a "guest user" devise gem as well last night.   I will come back soon once I play around with this and check